# Vectorising a sum of scalar multiplied by a matrix, where the scaler is an element of a list

Tags: python, vectorization

I'm trying to vectorise the following

```
a = np.array([1,2])
b = np.array([[5,5],[5,5]])
target = 0
for _ in a:
    target = target + _ * b
```

The above yields a 2x2 matrix where all entries are 15. How can I achieve this through vectorisation? I've been trying to cast a to be two 2x2 matrices, but I'm not getting anywhere

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This looks like a simple:

```
b * a.sum()
```

Output:

```
array([[15, 15],
       [15, 15]])
```

Comment: I realised that my question wasn't a good minimal representation of my problem. Thank you for correctly answering this question.